# Trocar estrutura de icones no javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou iniciando em desenvolvimento e estou com uma missão que to batendo cabeça e não sei como terminar.

Preciso trocar tag´s `<i>` por `<svg><use></svg>`. Dessa forma deixo de chamar por `class` e passo à chamar pelo `id`, conforme segue código abaixo.

Gostaria de manipular pelo `js`. Onde houver `<i class="ico-nomedoicone">` no HTML, fosse alterado para

```
<svg class="icon"><use xlink:href="icons/icons.svg#icon-nomedoicone"/></svg>
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar com uma idéia de código?

Pensei em algo assim...

```
var i = document.querySelectorAll("i");
        for(var i=0;i<=i.length;i++) {
            if(i[s].className == "ico-") { 
            i[i].innerHTML = "<svg class='icon'><use xlink:href='icons/icons.svg#icon-italic'/></svg>"; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tem 2 problemas: você usa `i` para duas coisas diferentes, e a comparação com `==` não vai considerar coincidência parcial das strings.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o método [**replaceWith**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/replaceWith).

```
<!DOCTYPE hml>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title of the document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <span>Span (Not replaced)</span>
        <i>Italic (Not replaced)</i>
        <i class="icon-android">Icon (Replace)</i>
        <i class="icon">Icon (Not replaced)</i>
        <i class="icon-test">Second Icon (Replace)</i>

        <button type="button">Substituir icons</button>

        <script>
            const btn = document.querySelector("button");

            btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
                var elements = document.querySelectorAll("i[class*=icon-]");

                elements.forEach(element => {
                    let div = document.createElement("div");
                    div.innerHTML = "<svg class=\"icon\"><use xlink:href='android-icon.svg#android'/></svg>";

                    element.replaceWith( div.firstChild );
                })
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

É necessário que você crie um elemento (com o `document.createElement`) temporário, caso você passe o `html` "direto" o JavaScript irá considerar como `string` e escrever o código na tela.

**Para demonstração siga os passos abaixo:**

1. Copie e cole o código acima em uma página `.html`
2. Baixe a imagem https://cdn.svgporn.com/logos/android-icon.svg
3. Adicione a imagem baixada no mesmo diretório onde você criou o `.html` acima.
4. Acesse através do seu servidor.

Comment: Agradeço a ajuda, testei aqui, mas nada ainda, não aparece o icone!

Comment: @PriscilaNeu O código está tudo OK. Verifique se apenas o código `<svg class="icon"><use xlink:href="icons/icons.svg#icon-nomedoicone"/></svg>` funciona. Adicionei um passo a passo para você checar a demonstração.

Answer (score 0):

Uma outra forma é usando **[`createDocumentFragment()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment)**. No exemplo abaixo incluí um `<circle>` apenas para ilustração, você deve apagar.

```js
let els = document.querySelectorAll("i[class*='icon-']");
let frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

for(let item of els){
   let svg = '<svg class="icon"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" /><use xlink:href="icons/icons.svg#'+item.classList+'" /></svg>';
   item.innerHTML = svg;
   frag.appendChild(item.removeChild(item.firstChild));
   item.parentNode.replaceChild(frag, item);
}
```

```html
<i class="icon-nomedoicone">elemento 1</i>
<i class="icon-italic">elemento 2</i>
```